# redirect input to telnet which are written in some file

Tags: telnet

I have one file input.txt containing commands which needs to be typed after telnetting to one ip address. How can I do this, without typing all commands one after the another in to telnet session?

Comment: What operating system and which telnet client are you using?

Comment: windows 7 os, xquery application to telnet to board